# Gradle, Spring boot. Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MFsS.png)

I have a spring boot application, which is integrated with Gradle. After I executed task instalDist, which create a executable script. I can not run this script, because I'm getting error like:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class some.package
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: some.package
```

I can execute jar file, it is no problem. I can also run project by IDE. But I cannot run it with this script after ran the instalDist

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'application-plugin'
    id 'groovy'
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.3.1.RELEASE"

}


dependencies {
some dependencies ..
}
```

Btw. I created similar project with same settings and it works corectly, but this doesn't work.

Comment: can you share with us the gradle.build file and folder structure of the project

Comment: I updated the question with build.gradle and project structure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `mainClassName` for the spring boot application.

```
mainClassName = 'com.example.MySpringBootApplication'
```

Comment: I added the mainClassName, but its doesn't work, I still getting error ClassNotFound exception.